# Button stays disabled until second click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Good Morning,

I have a list of items with a prev. & next button. When the user is at the start of the list the prev button is disabled. Clicking next takes them to the next record and my click handler sets the prev button enabled true. However in the emulator it doesn't show the button enabled. Clicking next moves me to the third record and again the handler sets the prev button enabled but this time it does become enabled in the emulator. I'm grasping at straw here but do I need to invalidate and redraw or something?? I don't understand why such an elementary task is not working.

In XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_PrevLift"
    ...
    android:enabled="false"
    android:onClick="btn_PrevLiftClick" />
```

In the handler code:

```
private void UpdateNavButtonStatus(int z)
{
     ...
     btn_Next.setEnabled(true);
 btn_Prev.setEnabled(true);
     ....
}
```

No just to show you how little I know about what I'm doing how come when I look at the variable values in Eclipse debug I can't see the enabled property in any state???

[image]

**More Info**
Very odd to me at least. If I move from using XML defined event handlers to programatically defined as below it works great!!!???

```
btn_Nxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Call helper methods etc...
    }
 });
```

**I think I have it but not sure exactly why**

So when I was trying to get a handle on my Button objects I was using the View.findViewById(etc). When I changed from XML to the programatically declared event handler I used ViewGroup.findViewById. Reverting back to xml if I use the ViewGroup I get a "different" handle that seems to work...????

Comment: For what it is worth, "enabled" is stored as a bit wise value in `mViewFlags`. Post more of `UpdateNavButtonStatus(int z)` and double check that `z` is what you think it is.

Comment: Did you define the states for buttons?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? It sounds like something is going wrong there.

Comment: FWIW mViewFlags looks like this: mViewFlags 402669601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the problem and of course the problem is me. I was enabling the button and then the ListView was updating to the next record. Of course my enabled button was one behind so it appeared that when I clicked a second time the button suddenly enable but that is not the case. When I clicked a second time we moved to record three and showed button for record two which was enabled.

See my buttons were part of my ListView and new buttons were being drawn for each record. OOHHHH it makes so much sense now how everything was behaving.

Anyway I moved the buttons off the ListView layout so they remain constant as the user navigates through the records.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,so what you can do is declare a variable count and on the click f button next increment the value of count..and on the click of Back button decrement the value of count and give the condition that while count<0 the task of the back button is done else nothing

Comment: Yes that is something I am doing. My problem is getting the disabled button to enable using setEnabled.

Comment: Then initially set btn_back.setClickable(false); and then on the click of next button set btn_back.setClickable(true);

Comment: OK I'm getting confused. If I set clickable to false then yes...it doesn't click but the ui still gives the appearance of an enabled button and I can hears user calling with bug reports now???

Comment: So what do you want that the user is unable to even see the button??
you can even hide it